# How to animate a closed string as in string theory

Tags: physics

How would I get a circle string to wiggle, as in the attached link? https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x7tvtxv

[image]

Comment: you could just use shapekeys, or Displace modifier... what have you tried so far and why weren't you satisfied?

Comment: Also, maybe look into using a Wave modifier as well.

Comment: shapekeys worked thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think he has used a *Displace* modifier:

- Create a circle, extrude, deform a bit, give it a *Displace* modifier and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. Choose the *Displace Direction*:

[image]

- In the *Displace* modifier, click on *Texture > New*, and in the *Texture* tab, go select the *Clouds* texture. Play with the *Size* and *Depth*.

[image]

- When you'll move the circle it will deform along the given direction.

[image]